# what is the support for cli az cosmosdb access to container data?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cli2

Does the az cosmosdb subgroup support accessing the data in a container?  I'm looking to retrieve the json data as shown in the Data Explorer image (Json snippet shown in bottom right corner)
[image]

I've looked at sub group commands like

> az cosmosdb sql container show

> az cosmosdb sql container throughput show

but these are not related to accessing the data. If the cli commands don't support data query access, I assume the cosmosdb API does.  Any information on accessing this data appreciated

Answer (score 1):

az cli does not have any access to data in Cosmos DB. It can only access it's control plane to manage Cosmos DB resources.

To access data in Cosmos DB you need to use one of the four SDK's as well as REST for SQL API or one of the native drivers for MongoDB, Cassandra, Gremlin and Table APIs.